# axios is not getting response

Tags: node.js, web, axios

```
const getReq = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('https://www.peoplestuffuk.com/WFMMCDPRD/LoginSubmit.jsp?txtUserID={user}&txtPassword={password}')
        console.log(res)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
}
```

I am getting 'Request failed with status code 500' whereas it's getting response on puppeteer and postman.I can't get around this! Is it because the site is large or slow.Any help will be very appreciated  [demo on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trBT2.png)

Comment: I'm going to guess that you need to put in the actual user id and password instead of `{user}` and `{password}`.

Comment: The problem is not related with axios or postman since you're doing a get request with invalid query params. It should use template literals, right? So the server isn't receiving the right data

Comment: nope i used my real username and password i just used brackets to hide my passwords and it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your

> const res = await axios.get('https://www.peoplestuffuk.com/WFMMCDPRD/LoginSubmit.jsp?txtUserID={user}&txtPassword={password}')

with

```
const res = await axios.get(`https://www.peoplestuffuk.com/WFMMCDPRD/LoginSubmit.jsp?txtUserID=${user}&txtPassword=${password}`)
```

Looks like you're passing your variables as a part of the string

Comment: nope i used my real username and password i just used brackets to hide my passwords and it is still not working